# Get Orientation of video while playing

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation

is it possible to get orientation of video while playing. I am facing the problem while getting orientation of video if i have recorded half of video as on portrait mode and half of as a landscape.if video contains both portrait and landscape mode then i want to convert landscape frame to portrait. can any one plz help me out in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try so far? Any research, any code?

Comment: i have done research but not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially get the thumbnail from video

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageFromURL:(NSURL *)videoURL
 {
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL: videoURL options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime requestedTime = CMTimeMake(1, 60);     
CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:requestedTime actualTime:NULL error:&err];
NSLog(@"err = %@, imageRef = %@", err, imgRef);

UIImage *thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
CGImageRelease(imgRef);    

return thumbnailImage;
}
```

after getting the thumbnail do this

```
 UIImage *img =  [self thumbnailImageFromURL:videourl];
 float width = img.size.width;
 float height = img.size.height;

if (width > height){

    orientation  = @"Landscape";

  }else{

     orientation  = @"Portrait";
  }
```

Comment: i can record video in both portrait and landscape mode now after recording video and  while playing it in a video player, as i have recorded half of video in landscape so i want to convert the landscape part of video into portrait mode.Is it possible?